# How to add a footer to the Oslo master page when SPM tags are present in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, master-page, sharepoint-on-prem

Many questions on this site ask how to add a footer to the Oslo master page, and it is advised to change the contents of the **DeltaPlaceHolderFooter** tag.

However, on my site, the Designer is activated, which means that I may only edit the .**html** file, not the .**master** file.

Therefore, the footer looks like this :

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false"/>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

What is the proper syntax to replace the **PageFooter** server control with a simple div of my making?

This page explains the syntax of everything (designer snippets and whatnot) except the one thing I need: "normal", plain HTML: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/general-development/how-to-convert-an-html-file-into-a-master-page-in-sharepoint.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the .html file with your own footer and may be hide the default footer.
Ex:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
<div class="ms-hide"><!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false"/>--></div>

            <div style="width:100%;background-color:#0072c6">
                <p style="text-align:center;color:#fff;">This is my footer.</p>
            </div>

<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct asnwer but it seems like the best practice in order to inject "normal" html into the master page is to do this : Avoid working with the oslo.html file, and instead do a "save as" on the oslo.master file to create a copy of it. This copy will not have a .html file attached to it, therefore you can modify it directly, and therefore you don't have to deal with the SPM tags that riddle the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems append footer to `s4-bodyContainer` make better effect.

[image]
[image]
[image]